# xdotool: How to test if current window is of certain class in bash script?

Tags: bash, xdotool

I want to do some specific things in a bash script if the current window belongs to the Firefox class

- I am aware of:

```
xdotool getactivewindow
```

and

```
xdotool search -class firefox
```

then I could do some test to know if the former result is in the latter list inside my bash script but:

- Is there a better way to do that with xdotool?

NB: I am also aware that Autokey can do the trick but I cannot make it work with i3wm see that open [issue](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/421)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
curr=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
firefox=$(xdotool search -class firefox)
if [[ $firefox = *$curr* ]]; then
    echo Current window is of firefox class.
else
    echo Current window is not firefox class.
fi
```

The if clause tests whether `$firefox` contains an occurrence of `$curr`.

Comment: Is this conditioned by whether one works on Wayland or X11 ? Asking because less than a year ago, I saw that `xdotools` was kinda quirky in that sense (with Wayland)... and, yes, I know:  a year is a looong time.

Comment: Tx for the good help. I can use that but I am very surprised that there is no an easy way to do that with xdotools

Comment: @Cbhihe To be honest, I don't know, sorry. I have always only used X11. But notice that the manual says "xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool" and later "It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions." So I guess only X11.

Comment: @pietrodito: consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers if the answer is satisfactory for you... ;-)