# How to get current window class name from script?

Tags: x11, wayland, window, xdotool

In my script I want to do different things depending on current active application. How can I get currently active window class name?

There is very similar question: [xdotool: How to test if current window is of certain class in bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588808/xdotool-how-to-test-if-current-window-is-of-certain-class-in-bash-script) But there the person want to just check if active window and searched windows by class name are the same. While I want to actually get the class name.

I have also seen the https://superuser.com/a/615946/873855 where person wants to get the window name. Mine task is very near to that. Can xdotool or wmctrl do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this in X11 or in Wayland for XWayland window, it it can be done with xdotool (returns the name of the application class):

```
$ xdotool getactivewindow getwindowclassname
VSCodium
```

If the active window is non-X11 (wayland), it will return:

```
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
```

Comment: xdotool: Unknown command: getwindowclassname
`xdotool -v`
xdotool version 3.20160805.1

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
CLASS_NAME=$(xprop -id $WINDOW_ID | rg WM_CLASS | cut -d '"' -f2)
```

I could not find documentation for `getwindowclassname`

Comment: You could not find documentation for `getwindowclassname` probably because your system's package is not updated: https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool. Anyway, it's good you have provided an alternative solution.